# AngularJS controller function not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 directives, "parenta", "parentb", and "childb". "parenta" and "parentb" are siblings, while "childb" is a direct child of "parentb".

I am trying to call a controller method from "parenta", however it is not working. For some strange reason, trying to call a method on "childb" controller FROM "parenta" is working instead. What is happening?

```
var mod = angular.module("app", []);

mod.directive("parenta", function () {
    return {
        template: "<section><div ng-click='vm.a()'>Rendered by a</div></section>",
        replace: false,
        controllerAs: "vm",
        controller: function () {
            this.a = function () {
                console.log("a called!");
            }
        }
    }
})

mod.directive("parentb", function () {
    return {
        template: "<childb></childb>",
        replace: false
    }
})

mod.directive("childb", function () {
    return {
        template: "<section><div ng-click='vm.b()'>Rendered by b</div></section>",
        replace: false,
        controllerAs: "vm",
        controller: function () {
            this.b = function () {
                console.log("b called!");
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Html:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <parenta></parenta>
    <parentb></parentb>
</div>
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJMpVe

Comment: you did not write an angular directive, your looks like a mix of half directive and half controller !?! check documentation please https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that your directives do not create a child or an isolate scope and use `scope: false` (which is the default).

That means that for a given scope, each directive with its aliased controller, create a scope property called `vm` - both **on the same scope**. And so, `childb` overwrites the `vm` property initially created by `parenta`.

You can check this quite easily - change one of controllerAs aliases to something else.

An easy fix - and the right thing to do - is to use either `scope: true` or `scope: {}`.

Comment: or rename value in `controllerAs` property :-)

Comment: @Grundy, I only suggested renaming as a test. I don't think it's the right thing to do, since a directive should not be "polluting" the scope where it operates. "Renaming" solves the current issue, but it's just waiting for a hard-to-trace bug to appear.

Comment: I will be creating an isolated scope, which suits my purposes.

Comment: @NewDev, yep :-) this is just yet another quick fix :-)

Answer (score 0):

I used link  function instead of controller.

Directive controllers are used in AngularJS for inter-directive communication, while
link functions are fully contained and specific to the directive instance. By interdirective
communication, we mean when one directive on an element wants to communicate
with another directive on its parent or on the same element. This encompasses
sharing state or variables, or even functions.

In the below code I commented the controller function and placed link function

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

</head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var mod = angular.module("app", []);

mod.directive("parenta", function () {
    return {
        /*template: "<section><div ng-click='vm.a()'>Rendered by a</div></section>",*/
        template: "<section><div ng-click='a()'>Rendered by a</div></section>",
        replace: false,
        link: function($scope,$element,$attrs)
        {
         $scope.a = function()
         {          
                console.log("a called!");
         }
        }        
       /* controllerAs: "vm",
        controller: function () {
            this.a = function () {
             alert("a called!");
                console.log("a called!");
                
            }
        }        
        */
    }
})

mod.directive("parentb", function () {
    return {
        template: "<childb></childb>",
        replace: false
    }
})

mod.directive("childb", function () {
    return {
        template: "<section><div ng-click='vm.b()'>Rendered by b</div></section>",
        replace: false,
        controllerAs: "vm",
        controller: function () {
            this.b = function () {             
             console.log("b called!");
            }
        }
    }
})

</script>


<body>

<div ng-app="app">
    <parenta></parenta>
    <parentb></parentb>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

or if we want to use controller directive then better to use **Directive Isolate Scopes** along with.

Unlike a controller, which is paired with a newly created scope when created, a directive is **not** given a scope of its own by default. Instead, it simply uses the scope that is available, based on its location in the DOM.

Isolate scope just means giving the directive a scope of its own that does not inherit from the existing scope.

so we use

> scope: true in our *parenta*

```js
mod.directive("parenta", function () {
    return {             
    template: "<section><div ng-click='vm.a()'>Rendered by a</div></section>", 
  replace: false,
  scope: true , // Isolate scope
 
  controllerAs: "vm",
  controller: function () {
     this.a = function () {             
         console.log("a called!");
         
     }
 }
```